# Why is my conditional expression != ignored?

Tags: conditional-statements, python-3.5

Here's my Fibonacci code using python 3.5

```
z = 0
x = 0
y = 1

while z != 317811:
    x = x + y
    z = x
    print (z)
    y = x + y
    z = y
    print (z)
```

I am wondering why this prints to infinity when setting the condition to

- z != 317811

but works when it is below this number like

- z != 196418

or a number greater than this like

- z!= 514229

I tried a different approach (z <= 317811) but it prints up to 514229.

Thank you for your time.

KD

Comment: 1. Clearly `z` is never exactly 317,811 at the end of the loop. 2. Until `z` is more than 317,812 it's less than or equal to it (can't believe I had to write that...) so you will get some numbers above that limit from your `print`s before the loop returns to the check. Remember that the check is only performed **once per loop**.

Comment: That's strange. For the avoidance of doubt, 317811 **is** in the sequence.

Comment: @Bathsheba yes, but evidently it's the *first* value printed in the loop it's reached during.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are increasing z value twice a loop, but only checking once.

What actually is happening is that z is increasing with the fibonacci serie. Last values of z are:

- 196418
- 317811
- 514229

But you are only checking the stop condition once every two assignment. In this case you are checking that 196418 != 317811 and 514229 != 317811, thus never matching it.

One possible fix could be to test if z != 317811 after the first print. Even if in this case I would prefer testing "<" instead of "!="

Answer (score 1):

You're only testing alternate Fibonnaci numbers as the stopping condition: 317811 is getting missed.

One fix would be to test *both* `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 1):

this is just logical problem 
you are printing two

> **z != 317811**
>   for this condition 
>   "z" 
>   is updated twice once in first z assignment i.e ***z = x***
>   but "z" again get updated at second assignment ***z = y*** and then "z" is not sutisfying the condition(**z != 317811**) and not equal to 317811 but it is now **514229**

Note: it will always work for number being printed at the second steps as this value of Z will be compared in while condition in loop